# Why KCL does not apply in case of this bjt circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt

[image]

Here in this problem current Io is taken as Ic (collector current), but I think that it must be divided into two parts one part flows from 180k resistor and another enters into collector of bjt, the second part which enters into collector should be treated as Ic.
But it is not the case so where am I making mistake in analysis?

Comment: Maybe the current in the 180k resistor is negligible as compared to the current in the 2.7k resistor, and therefore ignored, as an approximate analysis to simplify things

Comment: How do you know this is not the case? How accurately you measure this. current through 180 \$K\Omega\$ resistor should be around 200 times smaller them collector current . So your measurement precision needs to be considered.

Comment: *Why KCL does not apply* watch out with that ! The **L** stands for **Law** which means it should **always** apply. If you see that it doesn't (appear to) then assume **you** made a mistake. If the KCL would not apply then electrons would appear / dissapear, how likely is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Io is the collector current plus the base current.

However, the base current is very small compared to the collector current.  You say the gain of the transistor is 200, so 200 out of 201 parts (99.50%) of Io are the collector current and 1 part of 201 (0.50%) is the base current.  For many purposes, Io therefore effectively *is* the collector current.

So when you say "Io is taken as Ic", that's just a approximation good to ½%.

Answer (score 3):

Kirchhoff's voltage law applies in setting up the DC operating point:

$$\begin{align*}
9\:\textrm{V}-I_E\cdot R_C-I_B\cdot R_B-V_{BE}&=0\:\textrm{V} \\\\
9\:\textrm{V}-\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_B\cdot R_C-I_B\cdot R_B-V_{BE}&=0\:\textrm{V} \\\\
9\:\textrm{V}-V_{BE}&=\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_B\cdot R_C+I_B\cdot R_B \\\\
9\:\textrm{V}-V_{BE}&=I_B\cdot\left[\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_C+R_B\right] \\\\
I_B&=\frac{9\:\textrm{V}-V_{BE}}{\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_C+R_B}
\end{align*}$$

Estimating \$V_{BE}\approx 700\:\textrm{V}\$, this means \$I_B\approx 11.5\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$I_C\approx 2.3\:\textrm{mA}\$. And therefore \$V_C= 9\:\textrm{V}-2.3\:\textrm{mA}\cdot 2.7\:\textrm{k}\Omega\approx 2.8\:\textrm{V}\$.

I get the following pair of simultaneous equations using Kirchhoff's current law, instead, for the DC operating point:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_C}{R_C}+\frac{V_C}{R_B}+\beta\cdot I_B&=\frac{9\:\textrm{V}}{R_C}+\frac{V_{BE}}{R_B}\\\\
\frac{V_{BE}}{R_B}+I_B&=\frac{V_C}{R_B}
\end{align*}$$

Using \$I_B\$ and \$V_C\$ as unknowns, the above two equations simultaneously solve out to the exact same resulting equation for \$I_B\$ shown above. And the rest of the details fall out in the usual way, as well.

It all just works.

Answer (score -1):

This circuit will self-bias to VDD/2 ???? at the collector voltage, thus 4.5/2.7 = 1.6mA flow.

With beta=200, only 1,600ua/200 = 8uA Ibase must flow thru the 180Kohm Rb.

We have 4.5 - 0.6 = 3.9 volts across Rb, thus 3.9v * 5.5uA/volt for Rb = 21uA.

My initial (self-base to VDD/2) is wrong. But KCL is never wrong.